# Analysis: Differentiation problem

Tags: analysis, derivatives, rolles-theorem

I have been spending times on the following question for 2hrs, and I couldn't get any kind of proper proof yet.

Q: Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and differentiable on $(0,\infty)$.
If $f(0)=0$ and $|f'(x)|\leq |f(x)|$ for all $x>0$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x\geq 0$.

What I guessed are as follows:

First trial: Tried to use the MVT to show the contradiction when we assume that there exists a real $k$ *s.t* $f(k)\neq0$... but I failed.

Second trial: I saw that suppose $|f'(x)|= |f(x)|$ , we set a function $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{e^x}$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x\geq0$. But this is not the exact one since the original question involves inequality ($\because |f'(x)|\leq |f(x)|$)

Third trial: I tried to divide the domain into $[0,1]$ and $[1,\infty)$ and show that $f(x)=0$ for each of the intervals... Somehow I think I can prove in this way (for the interval $[0,1]$, used the property of compact set $\to$ so that there exists maxima & minima (supposed to be all 0 for this $f$ I guess)... and so on and for the interval $[1,\infty)$, I had no idea.

Will there be any suggestions on this question?
I would like to know if what I was missing or doing some error on my trials.
Need your help.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus is definitely your friend here. Note that $$f(x)=\int_0^x f'(t)\, dt.$$

Comment: Since the problem is tagged "derivatives" the FTC's cousin the MVT might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint for the interval $[0,\frac 12]$. Let $M = \max_{[0,1/2]} |f|$ and choose $x \in [0,\frac 12]$ with the property that $|f(x)| = M$.  If $M = 0$ you have that $f$ is identically $0$ on $[0,\frac 12]$. Otherwise $x > 0$.

Now apply the *Mean Value Theorem*.  There is a point $c \in (0,x)$ satisfying $$\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = f'(c).$$  Under the hypotheses of the problem this gives you $M = |f(x)| = |x||f'(c)| \le |x||f(c)| \le \frac 12 M.$ This implies $M = 0$.

The conclusion is that $f$ is constant on $[0,\frac 12]$. Can you extend this to the rest of the line?